# How to distinguish between FTP symlinks and actual files using standard unix command line client

Tags: ftp

Is there a reliable way to distinguish between a file and symlink while connecting to FTP server using regular unix FTP command line client?

If there is, is it possible to resolve the link and get the linked file along with its metadata (filesize, modification time).

One way would be to treat the link filesize (80 bytes) as a special size, but this does not seem to be a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Get your directory listings with `ls -la` and see how the symbolic links are shown just like in any regular Unix shell.

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 0   101   50 Oct 23  2014   thisisasymlink -> /path/to/actual/dir
```